# simple model using tensorflow 2 api gives huge loss and acc values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.array([100, 105.4, 108.3, 111.1, 113, 114.7, 120, 125, 129]),
                   'B': np.array([11, 11.8, 12.3, 12.8, 13.1,13.6, 13.9, 14.4, 15]),
                   'C': np.array([55, 56.3, 57, 58, 59.5, 60.4, 61, 61.5, 62]),
                   'Target': np.array([4000, 4200.34, 4700, 5300, 5800, 6400, 6800, 7200, 7500])})

df.head()

X_train = df.iloc[:, :3]
y_train = df.iloc[:, 3]

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = scaler.transform(X_train)

features = {'A': X_train_std[:, 0],
            'B': X_train_std[:, 1],
            'C': X_train_std[:, 2]}

labels = y_train


batch_size = 1
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1).batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset


def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
    '''Pack the features into a single array'''
    features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
    return features, labels


train_dataset = train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size).map(pack_features_vector)


class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.l1(x)
        x = self.l2(x)
        return self.out(x)


learning_rate = 0.1
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate)
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()


train_loss_res = []
train_acc_res = []
epochs = 100
model = Model()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    epoch_acc = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()

    for x,y in train_dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_ = model(x)
            loss = loss_object(y, y_)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

        epoch_loss_avg(loss)
        epoch_acc(y, y_)

    train_loss_res.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
    train_acc_res.append(epoch_acc.result())

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print("Epoch {:03d} Loss: {:.3f}, Acc: {:.3%}".format(epoch, epoch_loss_avg.result(), epoch_acc.result()))
```

I am using simple data and a simple model.

The results that I am receiving are:

```
Epoch 000 Loss: 32666856.000, Acc: 561536.963%
Epoch 010 Loss: 342012.625, Acc: 37158.075%
Epoch 020 Loss: 328074.844, Acc: 35578.772%
Epoch 030 Loss: 189751.594, Acc: 27069.794%
Epoch 040 Loss: 273142.312, Acc: 29358.673%
Epoch 050 Loss: 424036.625, Acc: 44175.562%
Epoch 060 Loss: 43667.957, Acc: 14025.812%
Epoch 070 Loss: 96341.156, Acc: 19105.350%
Epoch 080 Loss: 39308.691, Acc: 16228.386%
Epoch 090 Loss: 46950.699, Acc: 17407.053%
```

I can't find out what the problem is.

I tried other setup (more units, different metrics, loss) but the result is the same.

Comment: Is your question about how to fix it, or what the high "accuracy" means? Perhaps there is not enough data to learn the "pattern".

Comment: also with Adam optimizer and 0.01 (starting) learning rate i get:
Epoch 9650 Loss: 2673.525, Acc: 4330.981%
and it appears to be leveling off

Comment: @DecentGradient:I think the data is enough (I tried also with some more data).So, my question is how to fix this?Using Adam and 0.01 lr has again very high accuracy and loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss is so high because it is the **square** of the difference between the predicted y and true y. I noticed that you are using absolute error for your loss **metric**, but you are passing the squared loss into it.

1. Your average y is approximately 5766
2. The square root of your final MSE (i.e. the actual difference) is approximately 216
3. 216 is about 3%
4. If you train for 1000 epochs that will drop to less than 1%

There are two main problems with the accuracy. The metric used will not output a percentage, it is outputting the absolute value of the loss. The second problem is that the string format token `{:.3%}` is expecting a float between 0 and 1 which is then multiplied by 100 to display as a percentage.

See the following code in which I've divided the average MAE by the average of the y value.(And subtracted it from 100 so that it represents the "accuracy". This math only works when loss is not greater that the average y).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.array([100, 105.4, 108.3, 111.1, 113, 114.7, 120, 125, 129]),
                   'B': np.array([11, 11.8, 12.3, 12.8, 13.1,13.6, 13.9, 14.4, 15]),
                   'C': np.array([55, 56.3, 57, 58, 59.5, 60.4, 61, 61.5, 62]),
                   'Target': np.array([4000, 4200.34, 4700, 5300, 5800, 6400, 6800, 7200, 7500])})

df.head()

X_train = df.iloc[:, :3]
y_train = df.iloc[:, 3]

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = scaler.transform(X_train)

features = {'A': X_train_std[:, 0],
            'B': X_train_std[:, 1],
            'C': X_train_std[:, 2]}

labels = y_train


batch_size = 1
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1).batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset


def pack_features_vector(features, labels):
    '''Pack the features into a single array'''
    features = tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=1)
    return features, labels


train_dataset = train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size).map(pack_features_vector)


class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.l1(x)
        x = self.l2(x)
        return self.out(x)


learning_rate = 0.1
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate)
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()


train_loss_res = []
train_acc_res = []
epochs = 1000
model = Model()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    epoch_acc = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
    y_avg = tf.metrics.Mean()
    for x,y in train_dataset:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_ = model(x)
            loss = loss_object(y, y_)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

        epoch_loss_avg(loss)
        epoch_acc(y, y_)
        y_avg(y)

    train_loss_res.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
    train_acc_res.append(epoch_acc.result())

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print("Epoch {:03d} Squared Loss: {:.3f}, Acc: {:.3f}%".format(epoch, epoch_loss_avg.result(),100-(epoch_acc.result()/y_avg.result())))
```

Comment: Thanks for the exaplanation.My mistake, basically was that the mae at the print out was `{:.3%}` and not `{:.3}%` as you said.(upv)